# python counting motif across sequences in Fasta file

Tags: python, list, fasta

I'm trying to create a list of lists =for each DNA nucleotide (A,G,C,T) seen in a certain length motif in a file, the list for each nucleotide with count the frequency that nucleotide is seen in each position.

Example:

```
>this line of the file should be ignored, will always start with >
AGTCCCGCCCGGAG

>this is start of next seq
GGTCAGTCAAAAGTGAGCC
```

I would like my code to start at the first 'GT' it encounters in the sequence (here that is positions 1,2) and begin a list each for A, G, T and C. For each position up to a given length (input by the user) the value in the list for that nucleotide will increment by one. I am a students I'd like to learn how to do this with a list of lists in Python. For the seq above with the user input length of 6, I'd like the code to return:

```
alist = [0 0 0 1 0 0]
glist = [2 0 0 0 1 1]
clist = [0 0 2 1 1 0]
tlist = [0 2 0 0 0 1]
```

I need the code to look at all the sequences in the file (a new seq is denoted by the line starting with >) and update these lists, keeping those positions constant across the sequences and increment the appropriate position for each nucleotide. Here is what I had so far but it is quite an eyesore and I'm having issues with str vs. list types...

```
def position_frequency_matrix(filename, length):
        glist,tlist,clist,alist = [],[],[],[]
        gcount, acount, tcount, ccount = 0,0,0,0
        pos = 0
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
             for line in f:
                if not line.startswith('>'):
                    if 'G' and 'T' in line:
                        pos = line.index('GT')
                        for nuc in range(len(line[line.index('GT'):length])):
                            line = list(line)
                            pos += 1
                            if nuc == 'G':
                                gcount += 1
                                glist.append(int(gcount))
                            if nuc == 'T':
                                tcount += 1
                                tlist.append(int(tcount))
                            else:
                                tlist.append(0)
                            if nuc == 'C':
                                ccount += 1
                                clist.append(int(ccount))
                            else:
                                clist.append(0)
                            if nuc == 'A':
                                acount += 1
                                alist.append(int(acount))
                            else:
                                alist.append(0)
            return(alist,glist,clist,tlist)
```

Please submit responses in an easy to read format; condensed pythonic code can solve this problem but doesn't help a student like me learn python if I can't decompress the code and write it in my own way. Thank you!

Comment: What issues are you having? You stated a problem and showed a solution, that (we assume) does not do what you want. Is that the case? Where do you need help exactly?

Comment: Mostly having a problem keeping my types straight. This code returns multple lists (good) but they're full of zeroes. The code doesn't recognize that nuc == 'G' (or A,C,T) because it sees nuc values as integers. I then have issues if I remove the range(len(line[line.index('GT'):length])) to just the splice of the line because then I get out of range errors. Let me know if that isn't very helpful....

Comment: You should remove the "motif" tag from this thread - that tag is for questions regarding the Unix X/Motif graphical user interface libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. I don't have a full example data-set to run it, but here are some pointers. First:

```
for nuc in range(len(line[line.index('GT'):length])):
```

Here you are making a list of integer that starts at the position where 'GT' is found, up to index `length`. So, nuc is an integer, just like

```
for i in range(5):
```

What you (probably) are trying to do should be:

```
for nuc in line[line.index('GT'):length]:
```

Now nuc is a character in a string you are slicing. This is not terribly robust: what if 'GT' is not there? However it is a start, you can improve easily.
You are checking:

```
if 'G' and 'T' in line:
```

But that would also be true if 'G' and 'T' are not close to each other:

```
'GaccaTcc'
```

So the instruction `line.index('GT')` would still fail with `ValueError`. You can handle that exception instead and skip the `if 'G' and 'T' in line:` or just check for `if 'GT' in line:`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great advice! I've rewritten this a bit with your pointers but am having issues where it'll create the list with counts of each nucleotide but only for one sequence. Is there something wrong with my loops that it will not cycle through the next lines after a > line and begin the for nuc loop in a GT line?